# Pandas read_excel function incorrectly reading data from excel file

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have an excel sheet(.xlsx file) with the following data:

| Date 1 | Date 2 |
| --- | --- |
| 03/26/2010 | 3/31/2011 |
| NULL | NULL |
| 03/26/2010 | 3/31/2011 |
| NULL | NULL |
| 03/26/2010 | 3/31/2011 |
| NULL | NULL |
| 01/01/2010 | 6/30/2010 |
| 01/01/2010 | 6/30/2010 |
| 01/12/2011 | 4/15/2012 |

When I convert it to dataframe using

`pd.read_excel("file.xlsx",header=0,dtype=str,engine='openpyxl')`

It is reading all data properly except for the row items 3,4,5,6 which are being read as below:

| Date 1 | Date 2 |
| --- | --- |
| 03/26/2010 | 3/31/2011 |
| NULL | NULL |
| 01/01/2010 | 6/30/2010 |
| 01/01/2010 | 6/30/2010 |
| 01/12/2011 | 4/15/2012 |
| NULL | NULL |

It is causing an unnecessary data shift and hence affecting my furthur steps. Any reasons why only at this place it is happening and nowhere else in the data?

Comment: what happens when you run only `pd.read_excel("file.xlsx")`

Comment: Did you try: xl = ````pd.ExcelFile("file.xlsx",engine='openpyxl')
df = xl.parse("file")````

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem but this fixed for me. While reading the data, you can try:

```
pd.read_excel(r'file.xlsx', sheet_name="Yourfilesheetname")
```

Comment: Actually I have done it this way, `sheet_name` is also specified. But still the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is now resolved.
It was the issue with the index given by pandas to the Dataframe.
My table had headers, but **the pandas' index starts from 0 for the first row data**.
So I was being shown the next index number's data, which deceived me into thinking that read_excel has a bug.

Thanks for your support.